# Не работают яндекс цели

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Есть форма кнопки покупки товара на битриксе

```
<form action="/ajax/add2basket.php" class="add2basket_form">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="minus" id="quantity_minus_bx_3966226736_1137_cb49123d9d01f4f1e15216b03c62ec42">
    <span>-</span>
  </a>
  <input type="text" id="quantity_bx_3966226736_1137_cb49123d9d01f4f1e15216b03c62ec42" name="quantity" class="quantity" value="1">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus" id="quantity_plus_bx_3966226736_1137_cb49123d9d01f4f1e15216b03c62ec42">
    <span>+</span>
  </a>
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="1137">
  <button onсlick="ym('55407922', 'reachGoal', 'add_basket'); ga('send', 'event', 'add', 'basket');  return true;" 
    type="button" id="bx_3966226736_1137_cb49123d9d01f4f1e15216b03c62ec42_btn_buy" class="btn_buy" name="add2basket">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <span>В корзину</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Но не работает событие onclick, делал через

```
<form submit="ym('55407922', 'reachGoal', 'add_basket'); ga('send', 'event', 'add', 'basket'); return true;">
```

Но тогда страницу отправляет в другую страницу и белый экран, что совсем не правильно. Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var el = document.querySelector('.btn_buy');
            el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('click');
                if (typeof ym != 'undefined') {
                    ym('55407922', 'reachGoal', 'add_basket');
                    console.log('ya send');
                }
                if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'add', 'basket');
                    console.log('ga send');
                }
                return true;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

И если будете смотреть в броузере за консолью, надо включить кнопку в Firefox "Непрерывные логи" (Как она называется в других броузерах, не знаю)
Тогда при отправке формы консоль не очиститься и вы увидите вывод.

Суть в том что на странице может не быть ваших подключенных инструментов или они могут не успеть сформироваться когда вы уже кликаете на кнопку.
Данный код повесит событие на кнопку корзины после полной формировки страницы.
И убедитесь что на страницу вообще подключены инструменты метрики и гугла. Может на этой странице функций ya и ga  не существует потому и не исполняется.

---

ну кто вставляет код скриптов МЕЖДУ тегами head и body?

```
</head>
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var el = document.querySelector('.btn_buy');
            el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('click');
                if (typeof ym != 'undefined') {
                    ym('55407922', 'reachGoal', 'add_basket');
                    console.log('ya send');
                }
                if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'add', 'basket');
                    console.log('ga send');
                }
                return true;
            })
        });
    </script>
<body >
```

кроме того, не надо использовать одновременно скриптовые  события и кнопочные. Кнопочные могут (точно не помню, но могут!) перезатереть события скриптов. Поэтому уберите с кнопок атрибут onclick, я посмотрел в коде - он остался. 
И перенесите блок скрипта внутрь тэга

Comment: вставлял в футер в хедер, не работает. Можете посмотреть пожалуйста televizor14.ru ?

Comment: вставил в ответ добавку.